# How to say pork loin in Japanese

Tags: translation, food

How do you say pork loin in Japanese? Jisho.org says it should be ロース, but it seems too vague since I want to use it in a recipe. What about 豚ロース肉?

Comment: You not only answered your own question but also gave me a lunch idea.  When in doubt, try an image search in Japanese.  With 豚ロース肉, you will get this. http://image.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=top_lt4_sa&p=%E8%B1%9A%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E8%82%89

Comment: Did you do a search on 豚ロース レシピ? The top hits use ロース. Maybe similar somehow to your recipe? Also this might be a good terminology question for a butcher (loin vs. roast and what's the difference).

Comment: You shouldn't really expect to find the same cuts of meat across cultures. Even between countries with the same language the cuts can vary and the words for similar cuts can vary. Much more than you would expect.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure you'll find the exact equivalent to "pork loin" in a supermarket in Japan but I think you can find something close.

In a normal supermarket or butcher in Japan you'll find "thinly sliced pork roast" as「豚ローススライス」, 「豚ロース[薄切]{うすぎ}り」, 「豚ロースしゃぶしゃぶ[用]{よう}」, 「豚[肩]{かた}ローススライス」, 「豚肩ロース薄切り」, 「豚肩ロースしゃぶしゃぶ用」 etc.:

[image]

You'll also find 「豚ロース[生姜]{しょうが}[焼]{や}き用」「豚肩ロース生姜焼き用」, "pork roast for ginger flavored stir fried pork", which is a bit more thickly sliced:
[image]

Of course they have thick slices for steak and tonkatsu(pork cutlet) as「豚ロースとんかつ用」「豚肩ロースとんかつ用」「豚ロースとんかつ・ステーキ用」 etc.: 
[image]

And it's also sold in larger blocks as「豚ロース ブロック」「豚肩ロース ブロック」「豚ロース　[塊]{かたまり}」etc.:
[image]
[image]

Comment: 言語以外質問ですが、ブロックは普通のスーパーで売っていますか。洋風料理作るために欲しいですが、北海道に見たこともありません。

Comment: @virmaior　京都にいます。「イトーヨーカドー」「イズミヤ」「イオン」等の大型スーパーや、小さなスーパーでもお肉屋さんが入っているところなら、薄切りやとんかつ用より少ないけど、売ってます。ファミリービジネスの小さなお肉屋さんに行けば、値段は高いかもしれないけど、口頭で言えば出してくれるか、取っておいてくれます（お肉の専門店で、「売ってない」と言われることは、まずないと思います）。「もも肉ブロック」なら「業務スーパー」等でも売ってて、もっと安いんですが、「ロース」の方がやわらかくて美味しいですよね。私はロース肉のブロックで、「ローストビーフ」や「焼き豚」を作ります。・・・でも、もし、どうしても地域で見つからなけでば、ネットで注文とか・・・？

Comment: ありがとうございます！実際に買いたいものはローストビーフです。いつか、ダイイチまたさっぽろCo-opに聞きます。

Comment: @virmaior 数日前にイズミヤってスーパーで買ったのはこんなのでした → [豚肩ロース ブロック](https://scontent-b-nrt.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t1.0-9/10306386_579321732175714_891489244138138255_n.jpg)　で、これは数日前に「ニュークイック」って肉屋で買ったやつです → [牛 ローストビーフ用 モモ](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-9/10445948_579322845508936_1912337532389410816_n.jpg)　ローストビーフ用の牛肉は、ここではモモ肉しか売ってません。牛のロース肉って、焼肉用はあるけど、ブロックを見かけませんねぇ・・・。

Answer (score 5):

tbh it's probably ポークロイン　（see [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3)）

Comment: Seems you have been away from Japan too long, then.  Go to a supermarket in Japan and ask for ポークロイン, chances are 95% of the clerks would have no idea what that meant.

Comment: @非回答者: From what I understand pork loin refers to the uncut block, right? They don't sell that in supermarkets anyways. I've seen it been sold as ポークロイン in fancy shops.